# Convert kW generated per minute to kWh

Tags: power, mains, power-engineering, transmission, distribution-network

I have the data of power generated by a solar panel per minute in kW. I need to calculate the total number of kWh generated per day. How do I do this?

So far, I divided each value of kW by 60 and then added all the 1440 values(minutes per day) thus obtained. I don't think this is the right approach though. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you looking for coding solution or a spreadsheet solution? Do you want statistics like Min, Max , Mean % time per day Don't you want a histogram of solar kW/h per day or hourly charts. These can be useful too. in addition to Cum. daily total. Our energy provide does this online for us in any date range and by hour , day of week or charts for hourly daily, weekly, monthly hourly, historical trends etc and for you % capacity is important.

Comment: I was looking to show this data in a spreadsheet. I have the data of power generated per day per minute. I have to calculate the total number of units generated per day.

Comment: the approach you took sounds correct.  the result is the number of kWh you generated that day.

Comment: Assuming constant power conversion, the quantity of electrical energy produced in one day is: kW multiplied by 24 hours. So 10 kW over a 24-hour period would be 240 kW-hour. Note that kW per hour is meaningless in this context.

Comment: kW/minute makes no sense. It boils down to J/s^2, which is a very strange unit.

Comment: I have the voltage and current values per minute from which I have calculated the power. I don't have kW/minute, I have the power values at an interval of 1 minute each.

Comment: You  need to think about joules and joules per minute. One volt and 1amp for one second ---- is one joule, also one watt for one second. And a panel producing 200 volts at 5 amps is producing 1,000 joules per second.

Comment: Voltage per minute would be the rate of change of voltage. You mean one voltage sample per minute. You need to do some reading on units; it's important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Convert 60x24 data kW/minute  to Energy readings  in kWh/day

Correction **= SUM {Range  of kW readings/min} / 60min/hr**  = kWh for any array period you choose day week, month

( Range = 1440 results of   kW/minute every minute for 24 hrs )

If you use =SUM( ) or use SUBTOTAL() for each hour,
  - then you can plot hourly data then plot sum daily day and other interesting trends.

You can create a dummy column of numbers or convert time to the Hour

- then use =Subtotal{,} on the range for each hour and grand total per day

  - this uses a type number index so you can choose sum, max, min, average
- then use the group icons (-)to hide the day and plot the subtotal's per hour and or per day using grand-total of [kWh]

Then you can get daily plots averaged by the hour to examine your loss from the solar angle or cumulative plots per day

Here's is my consumption data online.

[image]

Comment: So I add all the 1440 values of kW and divide by 24?

Comment: oops sorry ... time to go to bed

Comment: no, divide by 60 (which it the ration between a minute and an hour). dividing before of after adding will get the same result, but dividing after adding is less work.

Comment: =SUM {Range of kW readings/min} / 60  is  1 step

Answer (score 1):

The approach you took sounds correct.

The result is the number of kWh you generated that day

Answer (score 0):

The idea of converting kilowatt-hours to kilowatt-days with a cumulative sum is no different than converting kilowatt-minutes to a cumulative sum of kilowatt-hours. Start by thinking you have 1 kilowatt load, and what it is in hour, minute or day of time.